# Applying functions to a factor-dependant submatrix

Tags: r

i have a symmetric matrix/dataframe, that looks like

```
structure(list(HQ673618_1 = c(NA, 90.8, 89.8, 89.6, 89.8, 88.9, 
87.8, 88.2, 88.3), HQ674317_1 = c(90.8, NA, 98.6, 97.7, 98.4, 
97.4, 94.9, 96.2, 95.1), EU686630_1 = c(89.8, 98.6, NA, 98.4, 
98.9, 97.7, 95.4, 96.4, 95.8), EU686593_2 = c(89.6, 97.7, 98.4, 
NA, 98.1, 96.8, 94.4, 95.6, 94.8), JN166322_2 = c(89.8, 98.4, 
98.9, 98.1, NA, 97.5, 95.3, 96.5, 95.9), EU491340_2 = c(88.9, 
97.4, 97.7, 96.8, 97.5, NA, 96.5, 97.7, 96), AB694259_3 = c(87.8, 
94.9, 95.4, 94.4, 95.3, 96.5, NA, 98.3, 95.9), AB694258_3 = c(88.2, 
96.2, 96.4, 95.6, 96.5, 97.7, 98.3, NA, 95.8), AB694462_3 = c(88.3, 
95.1, 95.8, 94.8, 95.9, 96, 95.9, 95.8, NA)), .Names = c("HQ673618_1", 
"HQ674317_1", "EU686630_1", "EU686593_2", "JN166322_2", "EU491340_2", 
"AB694259_3", "AB694258_3", "AB694462_3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("HQ673618_1", 
"HQ674317_1", "EU686630_1", "EU686593_2", "JN166322_2", "EU491340_2", 
"AB694259_3", "AB694258_3", "AB694462_3"))
```

These values represent sample similarities.
In the the first step, id like to know the average value for each treatment specified by the "_n":

[image]

The difficulties are in letting R know that the category factor is given in the row/columname. Also, my dataset is much bigger than the example, and the sample sizes vary within each treatment.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Your question in unclear to me

Comment: colmeans would apply means to the whole column, correct? That would include all treatments for a columns. But i would like to create a (internal) submatrix first (for all _1s vs _1s, for all _2s vs _2s and so on). The question is "What is the average identity of all samples with the treatment "_n"?" with n=1,2,3,4

Comment: Yup, it gave me a pairwise comparison, or?

Comment: I changed my dataset to have more samples per treatment. Makes it hopefully clearer.

Comment: and added a picture. in reality, my dataset is much bigger and consists of 25 treatments with varying sample size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution (assuming your data set called `df`)

```
indx <- gsub(".*_", "", names(df))
vapply(unique(indx), function(x) {
                          temp <- which(indx %in% x) 
                          mean(unlist(df[temp, temp]), na.rm = TRUE)
                          }, 
        FUN.VALUE = double(1))
#        1        2        3 
# 93.06667 97.46667 96.66667
```