# Creating vectors of temporary values created by unlist during vapply

Tags: r

this question builds upon [my former question about subsets of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735950/applying-functions-to-a-factor-dependant-submatrix)

My df looks like

```
structure(list(HQ673618_1 = c(NA, 90.8, 89.8, 89.6, 89.8, 88.9, 
87.8, 88.2, 88.3), HQ674317_1 = c(90.8, NA, 98.6, 97.7, 98.4, 
97.4, 94.9, 96.2, 95.1), EU686630_1 = c(89.8, 98.6, NA, 98.4, 
98.9, 97.7, 95.4, 96.4, 95.8), EU686593_2 = c(89.6, 97.7, 98.4, 
NA, 98.1, 96.8, 94.4, 95.6, 94.8), JN166322_2 = c(89.8, 98.4, 
98.9, 98.1, NA, 97.5, 95.3, 96.5, 95.9), EU491340_2 = c(88.9, 
97.4, 97.7, 96.8, 97.5, NA, 96.5, 97.7, 96), AB694259_3 = c(87.8, 
94.9, 95.4, 94.4, 95.3, 96.5, NA, 98.3, 95.9), AB694258_3 = c(88.2, 
96.2, 96.4, 95.6, 96.5, 97.7, 98.3, NA, 95.8), AB694462_3 = c(88.3, 
95.1, 95.8, 94.8, 95.9, 96, 95.9, 95.8, NA)), .Names = c("HQ673618_1", 
"HQ674317_1", "EU686630_1", "EU686593_2", "JN166322_2", "EU491340_2", 
"AB694259_3", "AB694258_3", "AB694462_3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("HQ673618_1", 
"HQ674317_1", "EU686630_1", "EU686593_2", "JN166322_2", "EU491340_2", 
"AB694259_3", "AB694258_3", "AB694462_3"))
```

and i was asking for a way to do blockwise averaging of values separated by their name suffix "_n". The solution was:

```
indx <- gsub(".*_", "", names(df))
vapply(unique(indx), function(x) {
                          temp <- which(indx %in% x) 
                          mean(unlist(df[temp, temp]), na.rm = TRUE)
                          }, 
        FUN.VALUE = double(1))
```

Can i introduce a line in which for each unique value of indx, a vector "temp_current_indx_value" is created that contains  all the values given by

```
unlist(df[temp, temp], na.rm = TRUE)
```

but only for the lower (or upper) triangle?

Thank you very much. I want to boxplot all these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my previous answer is linked to this question, I'll just add how you could have done it with my code

```
indx <- gsub(".*_", "", names(df))
sub.matrices <- lapply(unique(indx), function(x) {
  temp <- which(indx %in% x) 
  df[temp, temp]
})
unique_values <- lapply(sub.matrices, function(x) unique(na.omit(unlist(x))))
```

Or

```
unique_values <- lapply(sub.matrices, function(x) x[upper.tri(x)])
mean_values <- lapply(unique_values, mean)
```

Or

```
mean_values <- vapply(unique_values, mean, FUN.VALUE = double(1))
```

Comment: Sorry for spam, but you guys are really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
group.list    <- split(names(df), gsub(".*_", "", names(df)))
sub.matrices  <- Map(`[`, list(data.matrix(df)), group.list, group.list)
sub.triangles <- Map(function(x) x[upper.tri(x)], sub.matrices)
sub.means     <- Map(mean, sub.matrices, na.rm = TRUE)
```

where `sub.means` is the answer to your previous question and `sub.triangles` is the answer to this new question.

Also, you might want to replace `Map` with `mapply` to simplify the outputs from lists to matrices or vectors (where it makes sense.)

Comment: Cool, now  i can do boxplot(sub.vectors). However, is there a way to assign names to the elements of the list in sub.vectors, so i can specifically adress them?

Comment: `names(sub.triangles) <- ...`