# Creating submatrices from a dataframe, depending on factors in sample names

Tags: r

I have a huge matrix of pairwise similarity percentages between different samples. The samples are belonging to groups. The groups are determined by the suffix "_n" in the row.names/header names.
In the first step, i wanted to create submatrices consisting of all pairs within single groups (i.e. for all samples from "_1").
However, I realized that i need to know all pairwise submatrices, between all combination of groups. So, i want to create (a list of) vectors that are named "_n1 vs _n2" (or similar) for all combinations of n, as illustrated by the colored rectangulars:

[image: Example]

Reproducible code, as provided by helpful Stack Overflow members, dealing with identical "_n"s.

```
    df <- structure(list(HQ673618_1 = c(NA, 90.8, 89.8, 89.6, 89.8, 88.9, 
    87.8, 88.2, 88.3), HQ674317_1 = c(90.8, NA, 98.6, 97.7, 98.4, 
    97.4, 94.9, 96.2, 95.1), EU686630_1 = c(89.8, 98.6, NA, 98.4, 
    98.9, 97.7, 95.4, 96.4, 95.8), EU686593_2 = c(89.6, 97.7, 98.4, 
    NA, 98.1, 96.8, 94.4, 95.6, 94.8), JN166322_2 = c(89.8, 98.4, 
    98.9, 98.1, NA, 97.5, 95.3, 96.5, 95.9), EU491340_2 = c(88.9, 
    97.4, 97.7, 96.8, 97.5, NA, 96.5, 97.7, 96), AB694259_3 = c(87.8, 
    94.9, 95.4, 94.4, 95.3, 96.5, NA, 98.3, 95.9), AB694258_3 = c(88.2, 
    96.2, 96.4, 95.6, 96.5, 97.7, 98.3, NA, 95.8), AB694462_3 = c(88.3, 
    95.1, 95.8, 94.8, 95.9, 96, 95.9, 95.8, NA)), .Names = c("HQ673618_1", 
    "HQ674317_1", "EU686630_1", "EU686593_2", "JN166322_2", "EU491340_2", 
    "AB694259_3", "AB694258_3", "AB694462_3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("HQ673618_1", 
    "HQ674317_1", "EU686630_1", "EU686593_2", "JN166322_2", "EU491340_2", 
    "AB694259_3", "AB694258_3", "AB694462_3"))


    indx <- gsub(".*_", "", names(df))
    sub.matrices <- lapply(unique(indx), function(x) {
      temp <- which(indx %in% x) 
      df[temp, temp]
    })
    unique_values <- lapply(sub.matrices, function(x) x[upper.tri(x)])
    names(unique_values) <- unique(indx)
```

This code needs to be expanded to form sub.matrices for any combination of unique indices in temp.

This question is based on [my former question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780435/creating-vectors-of-temporary-values-created-by-unlist-during-vapply), which in turn was based on [my former question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735950/applying-functions-to-a-factor-dependant-submatrix).

Thank you so much!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: So, i want to create (a list of) vectors that are named "_n1 vs _n2" (or similar) for all combinations of n, as illustrated by the colored rectangulars. In other words, i need to expand the code to form sub.matrices for any combination of unique indices in temp.

Comment: There is a `combn`. Take a look at `combn(unique(indx),2)`. Or perhaps: `expand.grid(one=unique(indx), two=unique(indx))`